# Rails does not find file in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I have just built an app in rails and am trying to install a mailing system to the client and server side. When I try to run the application, the system states that the file cannot be found in the application.js file. Here is the error statement:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'global' with type '   application/javascript'):
3: <head>
4:   <meta charset="utf-8">
5:   <title>Vumos</title>
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', 'global', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9: </head>
app/assets/javascripts/application.js:17
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__160887971_97469592'
```

I the file 'global' stored at the base of the file tree, not in a folder. If this is the problem, which folder would I put this file in? If not, how do I include the file in the application.js file?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the directory breakdown and application.js content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a file called `global.js`  or `global.coffee` under the `app/assets/javascripts/` path, also, you should add the following require statement to `application.js`:

```
//=require global
```

Note: you could also use `//= require_tree .` on the application.js file to require all files on the javascripts folder, but it is usually best to require your file before that statement to ensure loading order.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. The app is now running smoothly and securely due to that line in the application.js file.

Comment: I am glad that worked for you, if you could upvote the answer for such reason.